# Why am I getting NoSuchElementException for find_element_by_id?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When trying to execute the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.co.uk/tennis/")
cookie_button = driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
cookie_button.click()
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: Unable to locate element: [id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]
```

When I look through the HTML on the page I can see the following line which is the button I want to click on:

```
<button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler">I Accept</button>
```

Picture of site below:

[image]

Picture of the HTML "Inspector":

[image]

(apologies not sure how to copy this as text)

Why can't Selenium locate the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ExplicitWait`

The below code works for me :

```
executablePath = r'C:\geckodriver.exe'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = executablePath, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.co.uk/tennis/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
print('Operation successful')
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks! Where you have `" Ifrmae xpath here"` - what should go here?

Comment: Iframe xpath from developer tool (Press F12 then do to Element section), I don't see cookie button at all from my end.. If you can give the HTML I'd help you out

Comment: You need to give bit more outer HTML of `<button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler">I Accept</button>`

Comment: Hi. I've added a picture with the HTML of the button - does that help?

Comment: @Jossy : You would need to scroll up a bit more till you find iframe tag, and from there you can copy paste the HTML here

Comment: Hey - appreciate you helping with this. Added a full picture of the HTML. Is this better?

Comment: @jossy : This is strange, in chrome I do not see I accept button but it's there in FireFox.. I'm working on this.. will update you soon

Comment: @Jossy : try out the updated code, it works for me. My assumption was wrong I thought it was in iframe but it is not.